# Background video appears half way in the page (HTML5 video element)

Tags: css, html, video, web

my website is a single page site, divided into two seperate pages (www.JazzAndRain.com). I'm trying a HTML5 video fill up the 1st half of the site, but somehow when it's loaded in Chrome and Safari, the video appears half way in the page. When you inspect element, the video will be pushed up. Does anyone know a solution to make the video load correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Margins are being added inline - by some javascript I assume. Stop whatever is doing that...

Comment: Thanks for the reply reekogi, by margins are being added inline, do you mean margins are added to the video? (just wanted to confirm). I definitly take a look at it and respond back.

Comment: No worries, yeah . The margins are not added by CSS, they are added inline to the video element, '#mainvideo'. in style="position:absolute; width:100%; margin-top:542.5px;...

Comment: Oh boy... I looked for 3 hours and can't seem to find how that margin-top is added. I even tried to do a margin-top:0px in jquery but it didn't seem to work. could you offer some suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? Looks OK to me now, margin-top:0 seems to be working?